# Rails - export to csv not loading values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Im doing an export to CSV in Rails everything seems to be ok no errors and the file is being generated, but only the column headers are been exported no other data.

Here is some of the code:

in controller:

```
@students = Student.where("START_DATE >= ? and END_DATE <= ? and COURSE_NAME like ?", params[:start_date], params[:end_date], params[:course_name]).select('name, course')
```

(...)

```
format.csv { send_data @students .to_csv }
```

in model:

```
def self.to_csv(options = {})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv << column_names
    all.each do |valeo|
      csv << valeo.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
    end
  end
end
```

What I have found as cause of the issue is that when I click on the link

```
= link_to "Export Records", student_path(:format => :csv)
```

@students is empty. I don't know why ? or how to solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried using the rails console to see what your query is returning?

Comment: students is returning the right info but before exporting to CSV students is nil and I don't know why since it shouldn't, so the query is fine first time the data loads but not when exporting